# Get the files of a deallocated VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, disk, azure

I have a VM from Azure (Ubuntu 20.04). I can't pay anymore and want to get the files, but I can't start the VM. I downloaded the disk (DOS/MBR boot sector, extended partition table (last)) and don't know what to do.

Comment: In what format are those disk images? Just raw bytes or vmdk, qcow2... ? Running `file` on them may help identify the format.

Comment: Why can't you start the VM? Have you tries `kvm -hda the-disk.img -m 2048 -snapshot` on it (where `-snapshot` makes sure the img is not modified)?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `file` gives me what I said above. And I can't start because I don't have credits to start.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I found another way to download the disk (think is better), its a .vhd file now (`file` says the same thing), I did the command above and this happens: `Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
kvm: failed to initialize kvm: No such file or directory
kvm: falling back to tcg
gtk initialization failed`

Comment: Yes, you need a Linux machine, Windows won't do and is off topic here. Note that qemu / kvm supports raw images (which would have been the format of those images you had initially if that's what `file` outputs for them).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ok, so WSL don't work for that, that's is the unique way to get any file from there?

Answer (score 1):

If the disk images are in one of the formats supported by `qemu` (raw, VMDK, VDI, VHD (vpc), VHDX, qcow1 and QED), you can make the disk available as a nbd device with (as root):

```
modprobe nbd max_part=31
qemu-nbc -c /dev/nbd0 disk.img
```

(`qemu-nbd` from the `qemu-utils` package on Debian-based systems).

Then, if the file systems are directly on partitions, mount them with:

```
mount -r /dev/nbd0p1 /some/mountpoint
```

(here for the first partition).

If LVM was used on the VM, you may need to also install `lvm` locally and activate the VM's volume group with `vgchange` and mount the logical volumes after that.

The `libguestfs-tools`  package on Debian-based systems at least has a few utilities to explore VM disk images, including a `guestfish` shell-like utility to explore them interactively:

```
$ sudo guestfish --ro -a slackware.qcow2

Welcome to guestfish, the guest filesystem shell for
editing virtual machine filesystems and disk images.

Type: ‘help’ for help on commands
      ‘man’ to read the manual
      ‘quit’ to quit the shell

><fs> launch
 100% ⟦▒▒▒▒▒▒⟧ 00:00
><fs> list-filesystems
/dev/sda1: ext2
/dev/sda2: ext2
/dev/sda3: ext2
/dev/sda4: vfat
><fs> mount /dev/sda1 /
><fs> ls /
.bash_history
.emacs
.kermrc
.less
.lessrc
.profile
.term
bin
conf
dev
dos
etc
home
inst
install
lastlog
lib
linux
lost+found
mnt
os2
proc
root
tmp
user
usr
var
zImage
```

Comment: I can't do the first command, this happens: `modprobe: FATAL: Module nbd not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use qemu:

### For `.vdi`

```
sudo modprobe nbd
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd1 ./linux_box/VM/image.vdi
```

if they are not installed you can install them (on Ubuntu is this comand)

```
sudo apt install qemu-utils
```

and then mount it

```
mount /dev/nbd1p1 /mnt
```

### For `.vmdk`

```
sudo modprobe nbd
sudo qemu-nbd -r -c /dev/nbd1 ./linux_box/VM/image.vmdk
```

notice that I use the option `-r` that's because **VMDK version 3 must be read only** to be able to be mounted by qemu

and then I mount it

```
mount /dev/nbd1p1 /mnt
```

I use `nbd1` because `nbd0` sometimes gives 'mount: special device /dev/nbd0p1 does not exist'

### For .ova

```
tar -tf image.ova
tar -xvf image.ova
```

The above will extract the `.vmdk` disk and then mount that.